# Push notification delivery speed using 3rd party services?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm currently using Pushwoosh as my push notification provider for iOS push notifications. What I'm noticing is that it takes on average 10-15 seconds to receive notifications after they are sent out. What I want to know is if this number is a normal number given the amount of traffic that Apple receives to their APNS servers? What kind of speeds do you get using Pushwoosh or other services? Is it time to switch to something more reliable, or is this just the nature of APNS no matter what provider I go with?

Pushwoosh is very cheap and affordable, but I'm starting to realize you get what you pay for, and that's not quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to depend on speed, sometimes a PHP call directly to APNS comes up right away other times it can take upto 15 seconds sometimes longer i would put this down to communication link with the handset and Apple Servers.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible problems

1. Your connection to pushwoosh.
   Just ping Pushwoosh API gateway cp.pushwoosh.com
2. Some delays on pushwoosh side.
   Send message, then go to https://cp.pushwoosh.com/notifications and find your message in the list, it must be first from the top. Status of the message can be pending, processing or done. In pending status your message is not being sent right now. It means that pushwoosh servers are currently very busy(really rare situation). When status becomes "processing", pushwoosh starts sending notifications to APNS immediately. In normal situation you should receive notification before your message becomes "done" in pushwoosh control panel. if not, see 4
3. Device connection.
   Even if you are sure that your device is connected to the internet - check again. This is the most common problem with delays.
4. APNS delays.
   I do not know 100% way to diagnose this, but if message status in pushwoosh control panel is "done" and you are sure about (3), there are some delays on APNS.

P.S.
If my reply will not help, feel free to contact Pushwoosh support(http://www.pushwoosh.com/contact-us/). They will investigate your case more closely. But do not forget to send them messageid of delayed message(you can find it on notifications page)

Answer (score 0):

We are currently using a Drupal module for sending push notifications and they're delivered almost instantly. (2-5 secs). I don't know which one, but if you're interested I'll ask my colleague...